# App storage files get deleted after app update for iOS, how to keep local files after update?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, updates

Kindly help me find the problem with data storage in an iOS app. App saves files in NSDocumentDirectory. I get path to directory with this method:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES
                                                         );
    NSString* folderPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String];
```

I want files saved there to remain forever until the user deletes the app. However, upon updating app from AppStore these files are inaccessible (deleted). Furthermore, this does not happen on all iPad and iPhone devices. What could be the reason? Should I be saving the files in another directory?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you need to find out the difference between devices where it works and where it doesn't.  Or, more likely, the difference between the steps the user takes to produce the different results.  It's possible that looking at the device's console log would give some clues.

Comment: Could it be possibly related to iCloud? It seems Documents folder gets automatically synchronised with iCloud. What happens if user changes his iCloud account? This could be the reason. I currently cannot specifically determine which devices are affected. I am getting complaints from users and I think it can be related to fact that files get deleted after the update.